# mootools css multiple attributes

Tags: mootools, css-selectors

I am trying to match in Mootools [version 1.11] a multiple CSS attribute as in this element:

```
<input type="radio" value="dev" name="radio_server">
```

I would like to match this element that has both type='radio' and value='dev' attribs. Tried this but this is not working

```
$$('input[type=radio][value=dev]')
```

also not working

```
$$('input[type=radio,value=dev]')
$$('input[type=radio && value=dev]')
```

this page: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/ has a JQuery solution is there anything like also for Mootools ?

Comment: which version of mootools??? works fine in 1.3.2 - http://jsfiddle.net/jTaYA/ - and in 1.2.5 http://jsfiddle.net/jTaYA/1/

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/BPZch/

Comment: Your first selector is correct. The other two are not.

Comment: As has already been shown, there's nothing wrong with the (first attempt) code you've given. Try making a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)/[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) test case showing how it's not working for you.

Comment: OK found it. Was trying with version 1.11 but there was no way. Now moved to 1.2.1 and all working fine with $$('input[type=radio][value=dev]')

Comment: in 1.11 you can use `collection.filter(function(el) { return el.getProperty("type") == 'radio' && el.getValue() == 'dev' });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned by Dimitar, in mootools 1.11, you could chain a `filter` function to filter your array, here is an example :
http://jsfiddle.net/HHQNE/

here is what's in there :

```
function radioAndDevPredicate(elt) {
     return elt.getProperty("type") == "radio" && elt.getProperty("value") == "dev";
}

document
    .getElements("input")
    .filter(radioAndDevPredicate)
    .each(function (foo) {
        foo.addClass("active");
    });
```

Comment: thx. fixed long time ago just by replacing with a newer version of mootools.